# How to open an offline image in a browser window from in-game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to have the ability to print an image from my game (Android build), the easiest way I can think of doing this is to have the image open up in an external browser window, then the user can just print it from there.

However the image won't be online, so the following script which I use to open online links isn't going to work :

```
 public void OpenURL(string url)
         {
             Application.OpenURL(url);
         }
     }
```

Is there a way of doing this? Maybe a way of modifying the above script to tell it a specific image file to open instead of a web address?

Or alternatively, any suggestions of another way for a user to print the image would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which folder are you trying to open the image?

Comment: Resources folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we know you are actually placing your files in `Resources`:

First of all [**DON'T USE `Resources`**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) this is Unity's own recommendation! See the links for the reasons.

---

Then note that all [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) are **packed** into the AppPackage and **no individual files** anymore!

It is impossible to open them in an external program.

You would need to

- [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) it
- export it to e.g. [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)
- only then you could open this exported clone

Comment: I put all my files in Application.persistentDataPath but still isn't working.I even tried using this api:https://github.com/Andy-Roger/UnityAndroidNativeFileOpener but doesn't work.

Comment: I tried using `AndroidContentOpenerWrapper.OpenContent(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename);`  and 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
              `Application.OpenURL(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename);`

Comment: in general don't use `+ "/"` for file paths! Rather use `Path.Combine` .. also possible that for Android you have to prefix `file://` so something like `Path.Combine("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath, filename)`

Comment: I could do it with an png image but whenever i try to open an pdf in my android phone says " file corrupted cannot open"

Comment: But when i go to my Application.persistentDataPath it opens normally in my computer

Comment: Does that mean i need to buy an asset to load the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not developing for mobile, you should just be able to pass a [`file://` uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) in instead of the more traditional `http` url. For instance:

```
Application.OpenURL("file:///C:/path/to/myfile.jpg");
```

If you are developing for mobile, on Android you'll need to us the `FileProvider` to open local files. On iOS it doesn't look like it's available, at least according to the documentation.

More details in the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html)

Comment: In my case i'm developing for mobile.How could i use this FileProvider?